# Can I prevent configs from getting deployed if there is no transform for the build target?

Tags: .net, msdeploy, slowcheetah

Is there a way with msBuild/Deploy to prevent a particular config file from getting deployed if it does not have a transform for the current build target?

I am currently using SlowCheetah to do my transforms.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

In any file you want, click right button, then properties. Set build action to None.

Comment: Let me clarify, if I do not have a transform for a build configuration then I do not want that config file to be deployed, but if there is a transform for another build configuration that same config file needs to be deployed.  I cannot simply exclude the file from all deployments as your suggestion says to do.